the disappearing assignment after handlering the data in fetch response
After using the fetch request to get data, I assigned some values of the data to other variables. However, when I call these variables in subsequent code, they show undefined, while inside the fetch request body these variables have values. What could be the reason for this, and how can I resolve this issue?
Here is the specific code:
let machineTypeArr, machineModelArr, machineBrandArr, machineSupplierArr, machineArr;
function getMachineInfo() {
    fetch('/machineInfoConfig?handlerType=getMachineInfo')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // console.log(data);
            // console.log(data.machineType);
            // console.log(data.machineModel);
            // console.log(data.machineBrand);
            // console.log(data.machineSupplier);
            // console.log(data.machine);
            // machineTypeArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.machineType));
            // machineModelArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.machineModel));
            // machineBrandArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.machineBrand));
            // machineSupplierArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.machineSupplier));
            // machineArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.machine));
            machineTypeArr = data.machineType;
            machineModelArr = data.machineModel;
            machineBrandArr = data.machineBrand;
            machineSupplierArr = data.machineSupplier;
            machineArr = data.machine;
            typeLen = machineTypeArr.length;
            brandLen = machineBrandArr.length;
            modelLen = machineModelArr.length;
            supplierLen = machineSupplierArr.length;
            machineLen = machineArr.length;
            // console.log(typeLen, modelLen, brandLen, supplierLen, machineLen);
            // console.log(machineArr);
            // console.log(machineTypeArr);
            // console.log(machineModelArr);
            // console.log(machineBrandArr);
            // console.log(machineSupplierArr);
            // loadTableInfo();
        })
}
window.onload = function() {
  getMachineInfo();
      console.log(typeLen, modelLen, brandLen, supplierLen, machineLen);
      console.log(machineArr);
      console.log(machineTypeArr);
      console.log(machineModelArr);
      console.log(machineBrandArr);
      console.log(machineSupplierArr);
}

I already checked with the search engine and gpt.
I don't know what the exact problem is.
I want to know why this situation will happen.

Within the final .then function you can call loadTableInfo but pass data as a parameter.  Within loadTableInfo you read the data from the passed parameter.

It does a solution to this problem and seems look more brief.

getMachineInfo doesn't return a promise that awaited on, so those console.logs run before getMachineInfo has done the fetch. I'd just make getMachineInfo async, and then await it at the callsite:
async function getMachineInfo() {
    const response = await fetch('/machineInfoConfig?handlerType=getMachineInfo');
    const data = await response.json();
    // The assignments
}

window.onload = async function() {
    await getMachineInfo();
    console.log(typeLen, modelLen, brandLen, supplierLen, machineLen);
    console.log(machineArr);
    console.log(machineTypeArr);
    console.log(machineModelArr);
    console.log(machineBrandArr);
    console.log(machineSupplierArr);
}

And, even better, return the data instead of reassigning globals.

Got it, i'll  look that in more detail.
